# how to auto toggle inactive timestamp in emacs org-mode

Tags: logging, emacs, timestamp, org-mode

I want to logging my todo list with active time stamp.
I added below my org file.

```
#+TODO: TODO(t!) START(!) | DONE(d!) CANCELED(c!)
#+STARTUP: logdrawer
```

And I added first todo.

```
** TODO Write Org config file
   :LOGBOOK:
   - State "TODO"       from ""           [2014-12-30 화 15:30]
   :END:
```

this inserts inactive timestamp. so this is not present agenda view.(Ye, I can see it Log
mode. but it's not a way I want to do).
I found org-log-note-headings variable. I changed inactive timestamp to active at state line(%t -> %T).

```
(setq org-log-note-headings '((done . "CLOSING NOTE %t")
(state . "State %-12s from %-12S %T")
(note . "Note taken on %t")
(reschedule . "Rescheduled from %S on %t")
(delschedule . "Not scheduled, was %S on %t")
(redeadline . "New deadline from %S on %t")
(deldeadline . "Removed deadline, was %S on %t")
(refile . "Refiled on %t")
(clock-out . "")))
```

this inserts active timestamp when state changed.

```
** DONE write org config file
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "STARTED"    <2014-12-30 화 15:57>
- State "STARTED"    from "TODO"       <2014-12-30 화 15:56>
- State "TODO"       from ""           <2014-12-30 화 15:55>
:END:
```

but I want to have active timestamp only current state. when i am first stage 
State "todo" is active timestamp, and second stage State "STARTED" is active timestamp 
State "todo" is inactive timestamp, and third stage State "DONE" is active state 
"STARTED" is inactive.

`** DONE write org config file
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "STARTED"    <2014-12-30 화 15:57>
- State "STARTED"    from "TODO"       [2014-12-30 화 15:56]
- State "TODO"       from ""           [2014-12-30 화 15:55]
:END:`

Don't you think this is right way? This simplifies my todo list, 
agenda view...
I found org-toggle-timestamp-type function. this toggles between 
inactive, active timestamp. but i have to execute this manually 
whenever todo state changed.
how to automate this?

Comment: In general, `state` is considered to be the keyword in the **heading** -- i.e., `DONE`, `TODO`, `STARTED`, `WAITING`.  `state` is *not* generally considered to be keywords within **a property drawer**.  Why would a `DONE` project with a closed logbook summary have an open time stamp -- i.e., done means finished, right?  In general, `org-mode` uses a specific regex to locate the `state` within a **heading** *instead of* **a property drawer**.  Property drawers can be searched, but that is a different issue.

Comment: I want to review my work in weekly/daily agenda view. Done means finished, but I don't remember all. I just want to explorer a day, a week, a month ago in agenda view. And i 'd like to follow link if i need remind of it. thank you @lawlist

Comment: What is the purpose of the `#+startup` statement in this case?